Converting Json to CSV using ChoETL issue not getting data properly
I'm converting Json complex data to CSV file.
This is my code:
StringBuilder csv = new StringBuilder();

using (var r = new ChoJSONReader(FileNameSample33JSON)
                      .WithJSONPath("$..getUsers[*]", true))
{
    using (var w = new ChoCSVWriter(csv)
                          .WithFirstLineHeader()
                          .WithMaxScanRows(10)
                          .Configure(c => c.ThrowAndStopOnMissingField = false))
    w.Write(r);
}

JSON:
"extension": [
    {
        "Test": "value",
        "value": [ "0", "1", "2" ]
    },
    {
        "Test1": "Test",
        "value": "20"
    },
    {
        "Test2": "Test",
        "value": "35"
    }
]

The issue is values 20 and 35 are missing because in the first object, the value field is a list, while in the subsequent objects, value is not a list. This inconsistency causes the values to be overlooked.
I want all values like



extension_0_value_0
extension_0_value_1
extension_0_value_2
extension_1_value
extension_2_value




0
1
2
20
35



How to fix this issue..?

Add an example of what you would expect the shown input results in as csv.

It's like the JSON file I mentioned in the question

Can you edit your question like this, so that we can see what CSV columns you expect?: https://i.sstatic.net/3KpVIAUl.png

"It's like the JSON file I mentioned in the question" - It cannot be. That's why I am asking.
